# Display a outputText and a selectOneRadio without manual reload

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem for displaying an "outputText" and a "selectOneRadio".

What I would have is : if the user fill an inputText, then an outputText and a selectOneRadio are displayed.
The main problem is that it works only if I reload manually the page.

Here is my xhtml page :

```
                 <h:form id="profil">
                     <h:outputText  id="teffect1" styleClass="colonne" value="#{messages['content.effectif']}" />
                     <p:inputText id="iteffect1" value="#{effectifBean.efCadre}" validatorMessage="test" >
                         <p:ajax event="change" update=":profil:wrapper" listener="#{effectifBean.efCadre}" process="@form" />
                     </p:inputText>

                    <h:panelGroup id="wrapper"> 

                        <h:outputText rendered="#{effectifBean.shouldRenderCadre() eq true}" value="#{messages['content.type1']}" /> 
                        <p:selectOneRadio rendered="#{effectifBean.shouldRenderCadre() eq true}" > 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['content.option1']}" itemValue="1" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['content.option2']}" itemValue="2" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['content.option3']}" itemValue="3" /> 
                        </p:selectOneRadio> 

                    </h:panelGroup>

                </h:form>
```

And my beam :

```
public class EffectifBean {

private String efCadre;

public String getEfCadre() {
    return efCadre;
}
public void setEfCadre(String efCadre) {
    this.efCadre = efCadre;
}

public boolean shouldRenderCadre(){
    if (efCadre != null && !efCadre.isEmpty() && !efCadre.equals("0")) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

}

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't work when you change the input field and then leave the field by tabbing out? A lot of starters have the incorrect impression that `change` event is fired immediately as long as you're still in the field. In any case, checking the JS console and HTTP monitor should give clues as to whether the whole ajax process has succeeded or not.

Comment: "In other words, it doesn't work when you change the input field and then leave the field by tabbing out? " YES this is the problem.
I haven't seen any errors in the console :-(

Comment: Is the ajax request fired or not? This should also be visible in the HTTP (network) monitor.

Comment: Remove `listener="#{effectifBean.efCadre}"` from the `p:ajax`.